# Программа на python выводит не то значение ячейки Excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Ожидал что программа будет выводить значение переменной "d" которую я задал.

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
os.chdir('D:\\python\\exel\\Новосозданные эксель книги')
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active ##Выбираем первый лист,он создается автоматически.
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("второй лист")
ws3 = wb.create_sheet("последний лист")
ws1.title = "Первый листик" #Переименовали 'ws1' лист с 'sheet' на 'первый листик'.
ws1.sheet_properties.tabColor = '1072BA' #Указали цвет листа ws1.
ws1 = wb.active #Выбираем лист ws1 активным
d = ws1['a3'] 
ws1['a3'] = 12 #Назначаем ячейке "А3" значение 12
print(d)
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Не смог разобраться в [мануале openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) и пришел к вам.

Мой вопрос - "Почему вместо "12",  "программа выводит (Cell 'Первый листик'.A3)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот пункт мне тоже помог, но вопрос остался не решен.Решение следущее:
к выражению `d = ws1['a3']` в конце надо добавить - ".value"
Это атрибут которые показывает значение указаное в ячейке указанного листа.
 Как должно получиться :`d = ws1['a3'] .value`

Answer (score 0):

> "Почему вместо "12", "программа выводит (Cell 'Первый листик'.A3)"

Выводит все правильно:

```
d = ws1['a3']  # переменной d присвоено Cell 'Первый листик'.A3
ws1['a3'] = 12 # в ячейке "А3" значение 12
print(d)       # в d значение не поменялось
```

Потому что надо сначала присвоить значение ячейке, а потом переменной:

```
ws1['a3'] = 12
d = ws1['a3']
```

Comment: Этот пункт мне тоже помог, но вопрос остался не решен.Решение следущее: к выражению d = ws1['a3']  в конце надо добавить - ".value" это атрибут которые показывает значение указаное в ячейке указанного листа. Как должно получиться : -  d = ws1['a3'] .value